# OR and AND operator inside ? filter

Tags: powershell

I have a long program which does as such:

```
[xml]$data = get-content "c:\somedatafile.xml"
$data.PRINTERS.PRINTER `
| ? { $_.USERS.USER -eq "$env:username" } `
| ForEach-Object{
      # install some printer with $_
}
```

I have also some COMPUTERS.COMPUTER to be compared with `$env:computername`.

How can I install the printer if at least one of the `COMPUTERS.COMPUTER -eq "$env:computername"`?  Or how do I include OR and AND, and possibly () inside the `?` filter.

Where can the meaning of the `?` filter be found out (Google fails with *monocarachter* queries)?

Suggestions about code sanity are welcome.

Comment: `?` is alias for `where-object` cmdlet. Now you can google it ;) and `get-help about_Comparison_Operators` in powershell to read about `OR`,  `AND` etc. etc..

Comment: You can also query "Get-Alias" to list all aliases in Powershell. '%' and '?' are also included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see *[Using the Where-Object Cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ee177028(v=technet.10))*

```
Get-Process | Where-Object { ($_.handles -gt 200) -and ($_.name -eq "svchost") }
```

Note that there is no associative operator is `()` (as not written on this page).

Comment: You should put your expressions in brackets like this ($_.handles -gt 200) -and ($_.name -eq "svchost")

Answer (score 0):

Here your snippet more readable:

```
[xml]$data = get-content "c:\somedatafile.xml"
$data.PRINTERS.PRINTER | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.USERS.USER -eq "$env:username" } | ForEach-Object {
      # install some printer with $_
}
```

No you have to add an neq If statement in the foreach and check if `COMPUTERS.COMPUTER -eq "$env:computername"`. If true, install the driver.